# Backing up a personal server on the net

Tags: linux, backup, webserver

I have a server on the net (meaning not within my local network) with fixed IP, DNS Name, etc. The server runs Debian, on which I have three "users": `root`, `admin` and `user1`.

I have set up the SSHD such that it isn't possible to log in as `root`, and that all the others can only be accessed with SSH-Keys. I generally user `user1` for most of my applications, whereas `admin` is a user with `sudo` rights to perform common administrative actions without loging in as `root`.

So far, I have made some backups by zipping it all and downloading the zipping. But now I want to act (a bit more) like a grown-up and make some automatic backup. I have a desktop at home which runs continuously and has enough space to get that backup. I thought about using `rsync`, as it provides some incremental file transfers (saving some bandwidth), and allows for similar backup.

Here comes the problem, as I could see two possible options:

- Run `rsync` as a `cron`-job on my desktop. But how to get a read access to all the files on the remote server? Either authorize login as `root` on the server, or create a pseudo-`root` with all rights as I don't want to go around changing the rights of each and every file.
- Run `rsync` as a `cron`-job on the server. Reading rights can there be solved if I run it as `root`. And it does not require any modification on the `sshd` for the server. But at the other side, I need to open some gateway on my home router, set-up a dyndns-like account to get a DNS for the variable IP, and essentially open my desktop to external accesses. Which is also not optimum as it is stands behind the firewall protection of the router currently.

Is there a solution to organise that backup without compromising on the security? It does not need to be based on `rsync` (it is what I know), but I'd rather have it:

- FOSS/Linux-based,
- Bandwidth saving (incremental...),
- Encrypted (ssh?),
- Secure, and
- "Simple" to deploy.

Comment: Just to be sure, I'd like to backup / (with some possible exceptions, e.g. /tmp)

Comment: And have you considered running an `rsync` daemon on the server and contact that via `rsync` from the client, on demand/via `cron`?

Comment: @ClassStacker. Nope. I was sure I was overlooking some possibilities, which is why I decided to ask.

Comment: @ClassStacker: That wouldn't use a secure transport, would it?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to add `stunnel` if you don't have some kind of VPN in place.

Comment: @ClassStacker, I don't. The bandwidth is quite limited (reduced price). More things to look up. Maybe you could write it up as an answer..?

Comment: I guess Duplicity is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org) is a great backup solution and has encryption. It supports many different transport layers ssh/scp, local file access, rsync, ftp, HSI, WebDAV, Tahoe-LAFS, and Amazon S3.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I haven't have the chance to test it before. As far as I can tell, `duplicity` only allows to back up a local system to a local or remote system. I get a backtrace if try it in the other direction (from remote to local). Furthermore, it does not solve the issue of either opening the root login on the server or providing access to the desktop from outside.

Comment: You can backup from any system to any system. The network in-between has to allow a connection of course. So firewalls and NATs need to be configured correctly.